# Java printDailyCost method

Tags: java, string

I have been asked to implement a `printDailyCost` method which should call the getDailyCost method and format the value returned to two
decimal places. It should then print this value along with a £ sign.

So far I have:

```
public abstract class Suit {

    private String colour;
    private double dailyCost;
    private int trouserLength;
    private int jacketChestSize;
    private boolean available;
    private double totalPrice;

    public Suit(String colour, double dailyCost, int trouserLength, 
                int jacketChestSize, boolean available, double totalPrice) {
        super();
        this.colour = colour;
        this.dailyCost = dailyCost;
        this.trouserLength = trouserLength;
        this.jacketChestSize = jacketChestSize;
        this.available = available;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public double getDailyCost() {
        return dailyCost;
    }

    public int getTrouserLength() {
        return trouserLength;
    }

    public int getJacketChestSize() {
        return jacketChestSize;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public double getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public void setDailyCost(double dailyCost) {
        this.dailyCost = dailyCost;
    }

    public void setTrouserLength(int trouserLength) {
        this.trouserLength = trouserLength;
    }

    public void setJacketChestSize(int jacketChestSize) {
        this.jacketChestSize = jacketChestSize;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(double totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

    public void calcTotalPrice(int numDaysHired){
        this.totalPrice = dailyCost * numDaysHired;
    }

    public String printDailyCost() {
        return printDailyCost();        
    }
}
```

My Question is how would I amend my printDailyCost method to call the getDailyCost method and format the value returned to two
decimal places then print with a £ sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add them together and return it:

```
public String printDailyCost() {
    return getDailyCost() + " £";        
}
```

However I don't recommend to concatenate `String` with this way. Better use the following method using `StringBuilder`, that concatenates strings in the correct way:

```
public String printDailyCost() {
    return (new StringBuilder().append(getDailyCost()).append(" £")).toString();        
}
```

Or if you want to print it out to console, just do this:

```
System.out.println(getDailyCost() + " £");
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting me!

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
    java.text.NumberFormat format = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale.UK);
    System.out.println(format.format(getDailyCost()));
```